# how to pass the value for datetime field in where clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, where-clause

hey guys,
i have created a stored procedure, wherein i have datetime field in the select query.
here is what my query is

```
select * from tablename where publishdate like '%03/10/2011%'
```

is this possible, or how should i form a query my objective is query should return the records for 10-March-2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select * from tablename where convert(varchar(10), publishdate, 103) = '03/10/2011'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from tablename where day(publishdate) = 10 And Month(publishdate) = 3
And Year(publishdate) = 2011 --Let the required date be 10th March 2011
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The best method for doing this is:

```
Select * 
from   tablename
Where  publishdate >= '20110310'
       and publishdate < '20110311'
```

By separating the conditions like this, you are allowing SQL Server to use an index on the publishdate column (if an index exists).  The query I show would use a super-fast index seek instead of a scan, resulting in far better performance.